# When does word-splitting occur in bash?

Tags: bash

I used to think that understood bash scripting very well, but something recently has called my understanding into question:

I thought that word splitting works by splitting scanning inputs and then replacing anything in the value for `IFS` with a space.

I printed my IFS and it is

```
>>> echo “$IFS” | xxd
00000000: 2009 0a0a
```

which tells me that it should take convert all tabs, newline characters, and spaces into JUST spaces.

So,  decided to test this:

```
list_of_stuff=("\n")

for elm in "${list_of_stuff[@]}"
do
    echo $elm
done
```

I would expect that it would convert the `\n` into `\s`.  But, when I run this get the following output:

```
>>> sh test_bash_script.sh


>>>
```

..which tells me that it is not converting the `\n` into `\s` as I would expect.  When should I expect this conversion to occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array doesn't have a newline in it, it has a backslash character followed by an "n". When the shell executes `echo $elm`, it converts the `$elm` to '\n', performs word splitting (no whitespace characters found), and passes that to `echo` as its argument. `echo` then sees `\n`, and performs escape interpretation (some versions of `echo` do this, some don't) which converts it to a newline, and prints that.

Try it with `printf "'%s'\n" $elm to get a better idea what's happening:

```
$ list_of_stuff=("\n")
$ for elm in "${list_of_stuff[@]}"; do
> printf "'%s'\n" $elm
> done
'\n'
$ list2=($'\n')    # This'll give an actual newline
$ for elm in "${list2[@]}"; do
> printf "'%s'\n" $elm
> done
''
```

But... why did it print nothing that second time? It's because `$elm` expanded to a newline, which word splitting turned into 0 words, so it ran the equivalent of `printf "'%s'\n"`, which just prints two single-quotes followed by a newline.

BTW, you can also use `set -x` to get a better idea what's going on in cases like this. In your original case, it would show that it's executing the equivalent of `echo '\n'`.

[EDIT] To answer the questions about "turned into 0 words" and equivalent of `printf "'%s'\n"`: word splitting does not turn anything into spaces; it turns a string into a series of words. If `echo` gets multiple arguments ("words"), it sticks them together with spaces in between, so word splitting + `echo` can have the effect of turning all whitespace into single spaces, but that's not actually what word splitting itself does. Consider several examples:

```
$ var1=$' \t word1 \n  \t  word2   \nword3 \n \n '    # Note that $' ' converts escape sequences
$ printf "'%s'\n" "$var1"    # This prints the actual contents with quotes around, no further interpretation
'    word1 
      word2   
word3 


'
$ echo $var1    # No quotes, so it gets word-split; echo pastes together with spaces
word1 word2 word3
$ printargs() {    # Let's define a function to show what's happening more clearly
> echo "Received $# arguments:"
> for arg in "$@"; do
> printf "   '%s'\n" "$arg"
> done
> }
$ printargs $var1
Received 3 arguments:
   'word1'
   'word2'
   'word3'
```

Let's take a look at the `echo` and `printargs` commands in a little more detail. In `echo $var1`, the value of `$var1` gets word-split on whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines), which turns it into three words: "word1", "word2", and "word3". There are no spaces here, they've all been removed. So it executes the equivalent of `echo "word1" "word2" "word3"`, `echo` takes those three arguments, adds spaces between them, and prints the result.

Now, I defined `printargs` as a function that prints how many arguments it got, followed by each argument (indented and single-quoted). So in `printargs $var1` the word-splitting happens the same, so it executes the equivalent of `printargs "word1" "word2" "word3"`, so `printargs` reports that it got three arguments, and prints each one separately (no spaces, except those I made it add for indentation).

Ok, next series of examples:

```
$ var2=$' \t \t    \n \t   '    # All whitespace this time
$ printf "'%s'\n" "$var2"
'           
       '
$ echo $var2

$ printargs $var2
Received 0 arguments:
```

Again, let's look at the last two commands in more detail: In `echo $var2`, word-splitting finds zero words in the value of `$var` -- it's all whitespace -- so it passes zero arguments to `echo`. The command is equivalent to just `echo` with no arguments at all. So `echo` just prints a blank line (no space or anything). Similarly, in `printf "'%s'\n" $var2`, `$var2` word-splits to zero words, so `printargs` gets (and reports getting) zero arguments. Compare the output with these fully equivalent commands:

```
$ echo

$ printargs
Received 0 arguments:
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  i am a bit confused by your explanation.  when you say "...which word splitting turned into 0 words..." you mean that it turned that into a space right?  since that is what word splitting does using the default value for `IFS`.

Comment: Also, i do not understand how that is "the equivalent of `printf "'%s'\n"`" as you say.  How are those equivalent?  thanks

Comment: @guimption: No, word splitting does not turn anything into space; see my edit.

Comment: This is great - thanks.  So, to summarize:

- The shell first sees one long string, and then performs word splitting.

- Word splitting is done by the shell, not by the `echo` command.

- `IFS` is used to determine the characters on which to do the word splitting.

- Then, after the word splitting done by the shell, `echo` receives an argument (word) for each word in the splitted string.

Comment: @guimption Correct.